# import * as request from 'request' throws warning in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Whenever I run ng serve I am getting this warning 
    
**WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js
    96:20-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**

WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js
119:15-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/compile/index.js
13:21-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

and this is my localhost:4200 screen.

[image]

I am trying to make a https request where I can pass cert & key as option (because I am using self signed certificate on my node server). In Angular2 HttpModule there are no options available for sending certificate as requestOption.

Comment: The `request` library isn't intended to be used from the browser (it can be done, but it's way too bulky and is a massive pain to set up).

Comment: Then how about https (npm install https) module !